# Unable to enter user_id correctly by send_keys

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver, cloning

I would like to input the user_id automatically using selenium, but the original characters are not input and the missing characters are input.

ex. correct user_id-> abcdefg@email.com
NGｰ>　bdeg@email.com　
some characters are insufficient.

Code　is here.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import chromedriver_binary
import time

user_name = '******'
user_passwd = '***'

def wait_for_element(driver, by, value, timeout=30):
    return WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by, value)))

def Operation(url, user_name, user_passwd):
    op = Options()
    op.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    op.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    op.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)

    driver.get(url)

    # ページの読み込みが完了するのを待つ
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_id")))

    # ユーザー名の入力フィールドを探す
    elem_user = driver.find_element(By.ID, "user_id")

    if elem_user:
        try:
            # elem_user.clear()
            elem_user.send_keys(user_name)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            pass

    # パスワードの入力
    elem_password = wait_for_element(driver, By.ID, "loginInner_p")

    if elem_password:
        elem_password.clear()
        elem_password.send_keys(user_passwd)

    driver.find_element_by_class_name('loginButton').click()

    driver.implicitly_wait(100)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('notRead').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)

    add = 0
    while len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="listCont"]/a')) > add:
        if driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="listCont"]/a')[add].get_attribute('target') == '':
            try:
                driver.implicitly_wait(20)
                driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="listCont"]/a')[add].click()
            except:
                driver.implicitly_wait(20)
                driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="listCont"]/a')[add].click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(20)
            try:
                driver.implicitly_wait(20)
                driver.find_element_by_class_name('point_url').click()
            except:
                try:
                    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
                    driver.find_element_by_id('mailFrame').click()
                except:
                    pass
            time.sleep(5)
            try:
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
                driver.close()
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
                time.sleep(5)
            except:
                pass
            driver.back()
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            add += 1

    print('finish!')
    driver.quit()

def main():
    Operation('https://*******', user_name, user_passwd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm trying to adjust the time using wait, but the user_id characters are still being input with them missing. Which part should I adjust to make it work?

I will also write down the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mail_de_point.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "mail_de_point.py", line 88, in main
    Operation('https://member.pointmail.rakuten.co.jp/box', user_name, user_passwd)
  File "mail_de_point.py", line 40, in Operation
    elem_password = wait_for_element(driver, By.ID, "loginInner_p")
  File "mail_de_point.py", line 14, in wait_for_element
    return WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by, value)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I would like to solve this problem so that automatic operation can be performed correctly.

Please help me out with this.